# React: How to show firebase error message properly?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I made login/signup in my react app using firebase authentication. Everything is fine its only error message, how can I show my error message properly to the users.

By adding this code:-

```
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, enteredEmailValue, enteredPasswordValue)
    .then(async (res) => {
        navigate("/");              
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
    });

//JSX goes something like this
<div className={classes.form_group}>
     <button type="submit">Login</button>
</div>
<div className={classes.error_message}>
    {error}
</div>
```

The error message can be seen like this:-

[image]

But I just want "**Wrong Password**" message not this "**Firebase:Error(auth/**" before this.
If I use if/else statements then there would be more conditions which I don't want.
So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Mohit you can just need some change in UI like-

```
<div>
{error !== null || undefined ? "Wrong Password": null}
</div>
```

Using this code you'll just need to pass the text you want. Also you can try third party package like toastify. If you still facing issue just lemme know i will help you more.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, but if I try to login with an unregistered email, then how can I show "Email doesn't exist" message? It still showing Wrong Password, Like I mentioned above using if/else or ternary might not be a good way to show it, there could be various errors in a form, right?

Comment: okay then, {error === "Firebase: Error (auth/wrong-password)." ? "Wrong Password":"Wrong Email"}